# int[] shared between Java and C++?

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface

I have an Android app with two threads that share an int[] that is in the Application object. One thread is gathering/processing data from a Lidar and storing it in the int[], while the other thread reads the int[] and updates a drawn image. Each position in the int[] represents a specific angle, and the contents of each int represents the distance measurement for that angle.

The gathering/processing thread needs to be re-written in C++ to take advantage of existing code and to improve speed. I plan to use JNI.

What mechanism can be used to share the int[] between the native thread and the Java thread? It's not a stream, buffer, or producer/consumer model.

Comment: This native thread is a C++ thread is it? How about any IPC channels? Sockets/Files/SharedMemory?

Comment: IPC and sockets are message-based, and I'm not exchanging messages. Shared memory seems to a good candidate, but my question is, "how could it be implemented?"

Answer (score 0):

You could use sqlite3. It's native to Android, and the [library reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) is pretty readable. sqlite.org provides a good [interface specification for C++](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html) as well.

Word of warning: sqlite does NOT provide row/column locking of any kind, so you'll probably want to take a look at making a Singleton class as a wrapper for interfacing with the sqlite3 database, which COULD handle row/column locking to avoid race conditions.

A shared worker queue (with appropriate language wrappers)  may also work in place of creating an entire Singleton class (which I suppose would be a Singleton anyway) but your call.

An alternative could be implementing Firebase in your app. Yes, I know it's cloud-based, but it maintains a local instance as well. It also handles row/column locking optimistically; meaning the last to update is what remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JNI Function like [GetIntArrayRegion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) or [Jace](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074265/java-concurrency/integrate-java-and-c---with-jace.html)

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) is a sample code for JNI to get int array.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_IntArray_sumArray
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jintArray arr) {
    jint buf[10];
    jint i, sum = 0;
    // This line is necessary, since Java arrays are not guaranteed
    // to have a continuous memory layout like C arrays.
    env->GetIntArrayRegion(arr, 0, 10, buf);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sum += buf[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JNI_COMMIT to store changes inside array passed to C++ where elements of array are updated

You can use JNI_COMMIT and JNI_ABORT values as last argument of

```
(*env)->ReleaseBooleanArrayElements(env, array, body, mode)

+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| mode       | actions                                                   |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 0          | copy back the content and free the elems buffer           |
| JNI_COMMIT | copy back the content but do not free the elems buffer    |
| JNI_ABORT  | free the buffer without copying back the possible changes |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Take a look here, for samples of passing various arrays back and forth

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-013/